# How do I add AfterCheck Event handler to TreeNode when TreeView is added at runtime

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to create an event handler for a TreeNode AfterCheck event. I want to check all children when the parent is checked. The only issue is that I am not sure how to do this when the TreeView is created at runtime. This code assumes that I have a TreeView named treeView1 already on the form. What do I need to do to replace treeView1 with the TreeView that isn't there yet?

```
' Updates all child tree nodes recursively. 
    Private Sub CheckAllChildNodes(treeNode As TreeNode, nodeChecked As Boolean)
        Dim node As TreeNode
        For Each node In treeNode.Nodes
            node.Checked = nodeChecked
            If node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
                ' If the current node has child nodes, call the CheckAllChildsNodes method recursively. 
                Me.CheckAllChildNodes(node, nodeChecked)
            End If
        Next node
    End Sub

    ' NOTE   This code can be added to the BeforeCheck event handler instead of the AfterCheck event. 
    ' After a tree node's Checked property is changed, all its child nodes are updated to the same value. 
    Private Sub node_AfterCheck(sender As Object, e As TreeViewEventArgs) Handles treeView1.AfterCheck
        ' The code only executes if the user caused the checked state to change. 
        If e.Action <> TreeViewAction.Unknown Then
            If e.Node.Nodes.Count > 0 Then
                ' Calls the CheckAllChildNodes method, passing in the current  
                ' Checked value of the TreeNode whose checked state changed.  
                Me.CheckAllChildNodes(e.Node, e.Node.Checked)
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
```

---

Correct Code

Where I added the treeview, i added

```
AddHandler newTree.AfterCheck, AddressOf node_AfterCheck
```

Then all I did to the code above is remove where it says

```
Handles treeView1.AfterCheck
```

In the Event Handler declaration.

I was also able to add another event handler to change the cursor to Cursors.No if you hover over a child node and a hand if you hover over a parent node. This was added in the same spot as the aftercheck handler.

```
AddHandler newTree.NodeMouseHover, AddressOf node_MouseOver
```

Here is the actual event handler

```
' Event handler for node mouse over
    Private Sub node_MouseOver(sender As Object, e As TreeNodeMouseHoverEventArgs)

        If e.Node.Tag > 99999999 Then
            sender.Cursor = Cursors.Hand
        Else
            sender.Cursor = Cursors.No
        End If

    End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

New `TreeNode` objects that are added elsewhere in the program can be instructed to use the same `AfterCheck` method, e.g. by writing

```
Dim myTreeView As New TreeView 'create a new tree view
AddHandler myTreeView.AfterCheck, AddressOf node_AfterCheck 'add this speficic AfterCheck callback to the new TreeView.
'Add myTreeView to the GUI..
```

Comment: Never mind, you didn't actually mean physically add to the GUI. Got it and it works, thank you very much

Comment: Thanks @Blackwood, code has been edited. Do you want to generally have ANY TreeView that will be added have trigger this EventHandler, without you explicitily writing it? The easiest way would be to edit the code where the TreeView gets created, aswell. 
A really funky way would be to have a thread checking all TreeViews in the GUI, checking if they have your eventhandler installed (e.g. by seeing that it's null), and if not have it added.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt if adding handler's **make sure they are removed as well**; otherwise unintended consequences could occur (memory leaks)...

Comment: Does a handler automatically get removed when the form is closed?